# Forcing scons to use older compiler?

Tags: python, scons

I have a C++ project which is using boost. The whole project is built using scons + Visual Studio 2008. We've installed Visual Studio 2010 and it turned out scons was attempting to use the later compiler instead of the old one - and failed to build the project as boost and visual studio 2010 don't like each other very much - yet. We'd like to suppress this and force scons to use the 2008 version. Is this possible? How do we do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can modify the scons Environment() by just choosing
the version you want:

env = Environment(MSVC_VERSION=`<someversion>`)

From the scons manpage:

> MSVC_VERSION   Sets the preferred 
>   version of Microsoft Visual C/C++ to
>   use.
>
> If $MSVC_VERSION is not set, SCons
>   will (by default) select the latest
>   version of Visual C/C++ installed on
>   your system.  If the specified version
>   isn't installed, tool initialization
>   will fail.  This variable  must be 
>   passed  as  an argument to the
>   Environment() constructor; setting it
>   later has no effect.  Set it to an
>   unexpected value (e.g. "XXX") to see
>   the valid values on your system.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow morning

Comment: env = Environment(MSVC_VERSION=9.0) Worked.

Comment: MSVC_VERSION='11.0Exp'  for making 2012Express.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to redefine the CXX construction variable, ideally in your Environment:

```
env = Environment(CXX = "C:\\path\to\vs2008\executable")
```

Comment: Hi, sorry about the late reply, I'll give it a shot tomorrow